# How to reject direct query?

Tags: php

I am using a URL to query some posts by their ID.
http://domain.com/page-name/?id=123
Visitors click the URL and will open the page and get the right post.
However, if anybody want, he can input this URL in browser and get the post, he can even get a lot of different posts if he knows other IDs. How can I reject this kind of query?
By the way, my site provide embed code for post. So, I need to enable access from other website.

Comment: if it is session based then may be you can store page id in session and can check for page id in session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The easiest way probably would be to check the **HTTP Referer** via `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and make sure the visitor clicked the link on one of your pages. This will, however, prevent any kind of bookmarking as well.
- Another solution would be to use something else than IDs as URL parameter. Those would be hard to guess. You could use an **MD5-Hash** of the id + date or something instead of just the ID. (Of course you would have to store the hash in the database!)
- On some pages you can see another approach. It is mainly used for search engine optimization, but can work for you as well. Generate a string from the title of the post (something like "news_new_blog_software") and store that in the database. Then use mod_rewrite to redirect all calls of `http://domain.tld/post/*` to a PHP file and over there check if the string after `/post/` is in your database. This might look a little nicer than MD5 hashes, but you would have to ensure URL strings are not used several times.
- If you want to make it really secure there is basically no other way than using some kind of **login** to check the access privileges.

Comment: If use MD5, How my page knows which post to query?

Comment: As I said...you would need to store the hash in the database and instead of using `WHERE id ...` you would need to use `WHERE hash = ...`. (Make sure you sanitize the input to prevent SQL injection!) You could also just use the hashing function of the database and do `WHERE md5(date | id) = ...` or something. Lots of possibilities.

Comment: Great! I will try the "Generate a string" solution. Thanks!

Comment: OMG old "security by obscurity" is still alive. That's why I call this site evil. It is spreading not knowledge but worst and lamest practices in the world.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel Well...nobody stops you from not visiting SO anymore. It's not SO's job to educate people on best practices unless they are asking for it. In the real world people need to solve problems and SO provides help if they can't get it done themselves. Of course there might be an underlying conceptual misunderstanding. I totally agree with that. But trying to teach everybody who has a small problem about the wrongs of the world, will hardly help anybody. And that's what SO is all about: Help.

Comment: Sorry...my bad for thinking there might be any chance for a reasonable discussion with you.

Comment: Choose reasonable topic first.

Answer (score 1):

> However, if anybody want, he can input this URL in browser and get the post, he can even get a lot of different posts if he knows other IDs.

## Exactly. That is the purpose of the World Wide Web.

And there is absolutely no reason in rejecting direct queries.
In fact, from the technological point of view, **every request to you site is a "direct" one.**

You are probably trying to solve **[some other problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)** (most likely imaginary one). If you care to tell it to us, you will get the right solution.

Comment: The posts are documents belong to independent Authors. It's their rights to agree to share or reject share. Most are open contents, but some authors are using the site to host their business activities and I earn a small fee from them which is a great support for maintaining the site.

Comment: So, you want to limit not a "direct access" but *unauthorized access,* like Till said. You need and authorization then.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate some kind of secret key and append it to the link URL, something like
`http://domain.com/page-name/?id=123&key=1234567890`
Some specific data required to generate this key is stored in cookie.

You can use md5 hash of random value + timestamp + page id, saving that random value to cookie. Every time you get a request, you check if key is present in request parameters, if user has cookie, then calculate hash and compare it with the one in the request.

Comment: I'm not familiar to the cookie method. I'll try Till's solution first. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can pass id in hidden field and use post form method.

Comment: by post form, if people embed my post on their website, then, they are blocked too

Comment: encrypt it and then send.. you can use md5 for that .. there are other encryption functions also..

Comment: That's not a good solution. I like to call stuff like this "security by obfuscation". Simply hiding the ID will not prevent crafty people from retrieving every single post at will.

Answer (score 0):

You need authorisation, not this. This would stop people clicking through to your site from search engines or other websites.

If you don't want to implement authorisation/login, then why not try implementing the First Click Free: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=74536